# SVN and renaming the server it's running on

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I'm running VisualSVN as my SVN server and using TortoiseSVN as the client. I've just renamed the server from mach1 to mach2 and now can't use SVN because it's looking for the repositories at http://mach1:81/ instead of the new name http://mach2:81/

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the "relocate" option provided by Tortoise SVN. Just right click on the upper-most checked out folder, select relocate, and then enter the new URL.

Answer (score 8):

Just change the address of the svn repository using switch --relocate command.

$svn switch --relocate file:///tmp/repos file:///tmp/newlocation.
In your case it would be $svn switch --relocate http://mach1:81/ http://mach2:81/

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jahangir. This answer is also correct and I wish I could marked 2 answers as correct but I was specifically looking for how to do this in TortoiseSVN which is why I marked Gordon's answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

First google hit:
svn sw --relocate svn://example1.com:22/name http://example2.com:24/edc