# VisualSVN Server wants a username and password

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I've renamed my server and am trying to get to the VisualSVN Server repository via TortoiseSVN. In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69646/svn-and-renaming-the-server-its-running-on) Gordon helped me find the right command - thanks Gordon.

Now VisualSVN Server is asking me for a username and password. I don't recall setting one and if I did I've forgotten it. Any idea how to reset this username / password?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on how your Visual SVN Server is set up. If you are using native windows authentication, just enter you domain username and password. Otherwise, you will have to log into the machine running Visual SVN Server and reset your password there. Visual SVN Server provides a convenient tool for managing users, passwords, permissions, etc. This tool should be available from the Start Menu on your server.